# OneDrive on RDS Windows stuck listing folders and files

Tags: remote-desktop, sharepoint, microsoft, perfomance, onedrive-for-business

This is a bit awkward because I've already wasted tons of hours with no result, this is my last chance.

### Problem

OneDrive sometimes (90%) is stuck on loading folders and files, but just listing them. Sometimes crashes "explorer.exe" when it's stuck.

You can see the "Cloud" icon appear very slowly.

[image]

### Hardware (Dedicated VPS Hetzner)

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core
- RAM: 60 GB DDR4
- SSD: 500GB NVME

Virtualized with Hyper-V, but it's the only Virtual Machine on the host.

### Internet Speed

1000Mbps download
1000Mbps upload

Hetzner Datacenter Speed

### OS

Windows 10 Pro x64

Version 22H2 (19045.2546)

### OneDrive configuration

Installed with "OneDriveSetup.exe /allusers".

All users has "Files on demand activate" because in share point size is big.

Every user has his own OneDrive (with no use)

Every user has a Share point Sync (all files are there)

### Number of concurrent users

18 approx, with RDP.

### Daily Usage

Users connect with RDP to the server, uses Word, Excel and Outlook. No more.

### Edit1

We tried to change Windows File Explorer > Settings > View > Launch folder windows in a separate process. Seems to be more "agile" but still super slow.
[image]

### Edit2

We forced Windows Indexing to be faster. Still no luck, all seems to work at the same speed and the problem still persist.

[image]

### Edit3

On OneDrive, we checked "Install Insider Version", and it restarts with the new version. Seems to work a bit better, but still having moments of "eternal waiting" listing files and folders

OneDrive Version: Compilation 23.045.0228.0001 (64 bits)

Comment: Hi, what a/v you use ? I ask as it can hijack the explorer process to scan change. (I would remove it to test, if it make a change then maybe change the scanning method (on create/on change to on modify)

Comment: Hi @yagmoth555, thanks for your reply! We use "Crowdstrike Falcon", console is Cloud. Version of endpoint 6.51.16510.0.

I'll try to ignore users Sharepoint folders.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question. Instead, post the solution as an answer and accept it, otherwise the question will stay as unsolved in the system forever. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question if you find the answer.

Comment: That's good information and not unexpected. A remote desktop host can have hundreds of sessions. There's no way an application like OneDrive would scale up to that. I believe it used to be not supported at all. This effectively means it isn't a good option at all, unless that is a hard limit per RDSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long checking my server with a Microsoft Engineer, the only way to solve this problem is reading the official documentation about OneDrive.

This [LINK](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/restricciones-y-limitaciones-en-onedrive-y-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#guestaccounts) and the next image shows that we can only configure nine (9) OneDrive for Work or School accounts in one host.

That makes me get crazy, because Microsoft allow us to use RDS for large amount of users with the same server, but that users can't configure all at the same time OneDrive...

[image: OneDrive max users per host]
[Max OneDrive Accounts per host (EN-US)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#guestaccounts)

So, there are thre possible implementations for that solution:

1. Implement FSLogix
2. Separate users in multiple RDS Servers
3. Use Third Party applications that allows you to map SharePoint as Windows Network Drive
4. Mount "OneDrive as a Service", with Third Party applications, so one account is syncing with SharePoint and all users consumes files over shared Windows Folder (native)